# Access user drive data using client credentials flow with MS Graph API

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api

I have an issue with accessing user data using client credentials flow with MS Graph API.

I followed this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?tabs=http.

I want to read an Excel file which is shared with one of the users. Right now I get an error "Request failed with status code 400" without any explanations.

I am able to call this endpoints and receive data:

1. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users - list all users
2. [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7BuserId%7D) - get data for a specific user from the list

However, I am not able to query any user specific endpoints, for example:
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/drive](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7BuserId%7D/drive)

I am also not able to query shares endpoint:
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/{sharedFiledUrl}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/%7BsharedFiledUrl%7D)

I was able to find out that the issue is with my access token. Because when I use access token from MS Graph Explorer, it works as expected. But in MS Graph Explorer I am signed in as a user. So it is different from client credentials flow. And I want to do that with client credentials flow, because I do not have signed in user on the server and want this to be automated.

I checked my token which I receive using client credentials flow and it has the following roles:

```
  "roles": [
    "Sites.Selected",
    "CrossTenantUserProfileSharing.Read.All",
    "Sites.Read.All",
    "Sites.ReadWrite.All",
    "Sites.Manage.All",
    "Files.ReadWrite.All",
    "User.Read.All",
    "Files.Read.All",
    "Sites.FullControl.All"
  ]
```

Some of the roles are not required probably. But even with these it does not work. Any advice is appreciated as I am not sure what else to try.